# How do I change the background of an element based on class name and inner text?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that changes the background color of a div class with specific text content. I know ideally you'd want to search by element ID, but I don't have that option.

Essentially, I want to find `div` elements with `class="noclick work-order-status "` (the trailing space is intentional) and change the background color of those `div`s to yellow.

Here's what I've tried, which does turn the background of those `div`s yellow, but it also changes the inner Text to the text I'm searching for.

```js
function setColor(element, color) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("noclick work-order-status ");
for (i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
    if (elems[i].innerHTML = "Initial Inspection/Work") {
      setColor(elems[i], "yellow");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for it is because you are using an assignment operator in `if` condition.
`elems[i].innerHTML = "Initial Inspection/Work"`

Change it to comparison by using `elems[i].innerHTML == "Initial Inspection/Work"`

Comment: Oh word! I'm pleased to say I discovered this directly after posting, but I'm so glad for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an equal sign. You need 2 for comparisons. With the code you have you are assigning the same inner text to all elements of the same class.

`if(elems[i].innerHTML == "Initial Inspection/Work"){`

Answer (score 0):

it should be Comparison operators

```
if(elems[i].innerHTML == "Initial Inspection/Work"){
```